# How to get two are more values from a select query in lua script

Tags: postgresql, lua

How to get two are more values from a select query in lua script

Need a function to get the values as Array

```
please help to solve thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What module are you using to for `getsqlintdirect`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into `LuaSQL`: [luasql/manual.html#cursor_object](https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/manual.html#cursor_object)

With `LuaSQL` setup you can then do something like this to generate and use a `cursor` object:

```
local driver = require("luasql.postgres")
local env = assert (driver.postgres())
local con = assert (env:connect("luasql-test"))
local cur = assert (con:execute("select order_id ,material_id ,gutter from sampletable where box_id=260226")

local row = cur:fetch({}, "n")
while row do
   local order_id = row[1]
   -- do stuff
   row = cur:fetch(row, "n")
end
```

The cursor object allows you to receive a row as a table in lua, either with numeric or field name indices.